# Barra de progreso dinamica en ASP.NET con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, progressbar

Tengo este barra:

```
    #myProgress {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #myBar {
      width: @Model.avance%; //El avance lo cargo de una variable que me traigo de sql
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #007bff;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 30px;
      color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-50">
            <div id="myProgress">
                <div id="myBar" name="ctlBarra" value="@Model.avance" onclick="increase()">@Model.avance</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var value = document.getElementById("myBar");
tb = document.getElementById("#myBar");
progress = document.getElementById("#myProgress"); //store these, it's better

function increase() {
    value = value+10; // same as value += 1, but better
    if (value >= 100) value = 100; //keep it under 100%
    tb.value = value; // set the value of the text field     
    progress.style.width = value + "%"; // set the width of the progress bar
}
```

El ejemplo lo saque de internet.. lo que hace es que cuando le doy click a una parte de la barra, esta va aumentando de 10% en 10% el detalle es en el html que no puedo actualizar la etiqueta que indica el porcentaje que tiene la barra, alguna idea de com pueda hacerlo?

Comment: Es asp.net mvc no? Tampoco veo en el codigo ninguna etiqueta

Comment: Ten cuidado con la forma de coger los valores. `document.getElementById("#myBar");` te va a devolver "null", ya le estás diciendo que es el id, no hace falta que se lo especifiques con la `#`, coge esos datos con `document.getElementById("myBar");` (Eliminando la `#`)

Comment: @Pikoh no no tengo etiquetas, en el div meto el valor que tiene el progressbar @ Rabegi de hecho me estab marcando como null el value por eso, gracias..

Comment: Donde inicializas la variable value? Y ten en cuenta el comentario de @Rabegi

Comment: la incializo arriba el tb var value = document.getElementById("myBar");